# Check a checkbox inside a programmatically created column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I created a checkbox column inside a gridview using the rowdatabound event:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

               'RETRIEVE THE NUMBER OF REQUIRED COLUMNS FROM THE DATABASE:
                Dim newlist As New List(Of ID_CLASS)
                newlist = SELECT_ID(datenow)


                Dim i As Integer = 1
                For Each value In newlist
                    Dim check1 As New CheckBox()

                    'Adds a new checkbox column for each value.ID:
                    check1.ID = value.ID
                    check1.Checked = False
                    e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(check1)
                    i = i + 1
                Next
     End If
```

Now, in another function (in the same module), I need to check some particular checkboxes. This is the code I am using now (but is not working):

```
         Dim i As Integer = 0
         Dim newlist As New List(Of ID_CLASS)
         newlist = SELECT_ID(datenow)

           For each value in newlist
                While i < 24
                    row_a = GridView1.Rows(i)
                    Dim ID As String = value.ID

                   'IF A CONDITION IS MET:
                        Dim check1 As CheckBox = TryCast(row_a.FindControl(ID), CheckBox)
                        check1.Checked = True

                    i = i + 1
                End While
            Next
```

This is the error I'm gettings: 'OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT'
I think it is because the checkbox.ID I added is not rendered in the gridview. But i don't know how to add ID in such a way that it will persists in the module

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is ID the name of your Checkbox or check1 ? Shouldn't  `TryCast(row_a.FindControl(check1), CheckBox)` perhaps or am i mistaken ?

Comment: In the rowdatabound event, I added check1 as a new checkbox but its ID depends on the list i retrieved from the database(value.ID). That's why, I think its the ID control i need to "find". :) I also tried "check1" just in case, but unfortunately, it didn't work. :(

Comment: Ok . Can you perhaps add the cells index in the row. I mean the index of the checkbox column like.   `  row_a = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells[1]` For second column. I normally do that way in C#. Never code .vb before thought

Comment: A row can have multiple controls of different type. Although it would seem reasonable since the name is specified should be able to locate. I suggest you specify the control column/cell index as well.

Comment: Hi!  This is the code I used with your recommendation:  check_rtd = TryCast(row_a.Cells(i).Controls(0), CheckBox). Unfortunately, the error is: index out of range. But I think I'm close though :)

Comment: Pls see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assumption in your rowdatabound event you use `Dim i As Integer = 1` . Therefore supposedly no  textbox at index 0 . And theb in ou second method

```
  Dim i As Integer = 0 .
```

I have done similar thing in C# and it never fails me. Below is how i normally do. First of all Lets say you have a three column grid. The first colum is checbox column. you can access the checkboxes like below.

```
C#
int rowIndex = 0;

if(GridView1.Rows.Count > 0) //Check your grid for rows.
{
  for(int i=1; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  { 
     CheckBox check = (CheckBox) GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("checkbox1");
     //In the above, checkbox1 is your textbox name.
     //RowIndex is the row number/index.
     //Cells[0] assumin the first colum/cell of the gridview contain checboxes only. It can be 1,2 ..

     check.Checked = true;

     rowIndex ++;

  }

}
```

Note when you said "created a checkbox column" . Then i assumed there is a column for the checkboxes. THe column index is important . 0 for the first column, 1 for the second .....

in

```
VB
 Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

if(GridView1.Rows.Count > 0) //Check your grid for rows.

   for each Datarow row in Gridview1.Rows
      while rowIndex < 24

      DIM check AS CheckBox= TryCast(GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("checkbox1"), CheckBox);
     check.Check = true;
     rowIndex ++;
    END while

Next
```

I am not good with VB just attempting. But have coded similar feature in C# before and i am certain it works. Hope it helps.